# MS Access linked tables and referential integrity

Tags: sql, ms-access, foreign-keys

Is there any way to enforce referential integrity on two linked tables in access? I have an order table and order detail table both linked tables from SQL. PK and FK are set and it works for local tables in access but not linked.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Enforce referential integrity in the underlying database that is storing the tables.

Comment: The documentation will tell you how to create relationships: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/304466

Comment: That works for non-linked tables

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is No. You can code your way around it but that's a major task.

Besides, the referential integrity should be defined on the SQL Server.